# .NET CookieException "Cookie format error" when thread culture is not English - only in certain environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cookies, currentculture

I am trying to do some cookie management in an ASP.NET app that calls other web services.  I am encountering an error that I can reproduce **only in certain environments**.  My questions are:

1. Is the difference between production and development enough to cause this issue?
2. How could I figure out what is different between production/development?
3. What can I do to work-around this issue?

Following are the details I use to reproduce the problem.  The error that I see is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.CookieException: 
An error occurred when parsing the Cookie header for Uri 'http://example.com/'. 
---> System.Net.CookieException: Cookie format error.
   at System.Net.CookieContainer.CookieCutter(Uri uri, String headerName, 
         String setCookieHeader, Boolean isThrow)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.CookieContainer.CookieCutter(Uri uri, String headerName, 
         String setCookieHeader, Boolean isThrow)
   at System.Net.CookieContainer.SetCookies(Uri uri, String cookieHeader)
   at Program.Main() in c:\Sample\Program.cs:line 21
```

I have created a console app that reproduces the problem (relevant parts below).  Full code at https://compilr.com/adutton/cookiecutterexample/main.cs

```
string[] cultures = new[] { "en-US", "es-MX" };
const string cookieHeader = ".ASPXAUTH=SECURITYINFO; domain=.example.com; "
    + "expires=Mon, 06-Mar-2023 18:36:33 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly";

foreach (string culture in cultures)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CookieCutting with culture: " + culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

    CookieContainer ctr = new CookieContainer();
    // The following line throws an exception
    ctr.SetCookies(new Uri("http://example.com/"), cookieHeader);
}
```

This code works on my development machine (Windows 7, x64, .NET 4.5.50709) but **not in production** (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, x64, .NET 4.0.30319) where the code throws an exception for the `es-MX` culture.

If I remove the date from the cookie header, the exception goes away, which leads me to believe that is a localization issue with the cookie parser.  Perhaps this was fixed in .NET 4.0 -> 4.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @nunzabar pointed out, the problem is way the current culture sets a comma in the day-of-week.  In this case, installing the .NET 4.5 framework caused the problem to disappear.  I did not decompile the code to see the differences between .NET 4.0 and 4.5 but it was fixed when we installed the new version of the framework.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the comma after the day-of-week, as seen here: [Help With .NET CookieContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834522/help-with-net-cookiecontainer)